# How do I check what permissions Local System Account has on Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, local-system-account

Does anybody know how to check the permissions on the local system account on Windows Server 2008?

Comment: You might want to tag your question more descriptively.

Comment: Programmatically or manually? You may also want to ask at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Manually in Windows and this is a domain machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-Click My Computer-->Manage-->Local Users and Groups-->Right-Click User and Go to Properties-->Member of tab

Comment: Sorry This is for Domain, so I only have Active Directory

Comment: You should still be able to access My Computer locally from the DC.  Though I will admit I am not expect with the DC.

Comment: The local system account is not listed under Local Users and Groups
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts#:~:text=It%27s%20an%20internal%20account%20that%20doesn%27t%20show%20up%20in%20User%20Manager%2C%20and%20it%20can%27t%20be%20added%20to%20any%20groups.